# OpenCV Identifier CvSURFParams is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am using the code in [this](http://opencvuser.blogspot.com/2012/07/surf-source-code-part-2.html) article.

I have problem with this line :

```
CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(500, 1);
```

VS2010 Compiler says : `Identifier CvSURFParams is undefined`

I also linked `opencv_nonfree249d.lib` in my project but nothing changed!

Comment: If you're using 2.4.9, **don't use the C API!**. Use `cv::SURF` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  Aurelius said, the problem came from i mistakenly was using C API!